# Can a Flow "know" the specific Quick Action that called it?

Tags: lightning-experience, visual-workflow, action, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I'm hoping to create one flow and have two different Quick Action call it.

Wondering if it's possible for the flow to "know" which Quick Action initiated it so that we can build in some decision within the flow.

Best,
Eric